# Sqlite database connection lost at real time use of application

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have my database class that is extending *SQLiteOpenHelper* which contains all the steps to create the database instance and executing queries.

**DbAdapter.java**

Creating database instance to be used throughtout my application------

```
public static DbAdapter getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getParent() + "/databases/";
            mInstance = new IDDLDbAdapter(context);
            try {
                mInstance.createDataBase();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
```

Cursor for rawQuery ----------

```
public synchronized Cursor rawQuery(String sql, String[] args) throws SQLException{
        if(db == null || !db.isOpen())
            this.open();
        return db.rawQuery(sql, args);
    }
```

However, there are times when the database adapter is no longer available although still unaware as it is happening **at real time** with customers using the application **but not on** application debug.

I have many classes where I am using this for connecting and executing queries just like that-

```
protected static DbAdapter dbAdapter;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try 
    {   
        dbAdapter = DbAdapter.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());
    } 
    catch (ClassCastException e) 
    {

    }
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

   Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
   {
     Cursor cur = dbAdapter.rawQuery("select * from blabla WHERE 
     Activities='"+ activity +      "'", null);
     cur.moveToFirst();
   }
}
```

And then my work with the Cursor cur then goes on...

Is this code problematic ?

***I have three doubts for the problem -***

**1)** This line seems problematic --

```
dbAdapter = DbAdapter.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext());
```

This is because it was advised in some posts to avoid using `getApplicationContext()` wherever possible.

**2)** During application idle time database connector class's object got finalized(having no reference to database).

**3)** I am getting the database instance `onAttach()`. Is it advisable ?

Can someone shed a light on the road of problems to move correctly ?

Comment: you should close cursor with cur.close();